# Do all goblins in HP universe work at Gringotts or as Artisans?

Tags: harry-potter

The wizarding bank Gringotts is run by goblins.  We also know that there are goblin artisans because some of the artifacts such as the sword of Godric Gryffindor are goblin made. Do the goblins have any other career choice ? Or is the population of the species small enough that all of them can be employed by these two professions alone ?

**EDIT:**
From the [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com), there are some known goblins in other roles such as a spokes-goblin. But none in any of the classical careers [Healers, Professors]. Is this limitation in career choice due to not being able to use a wand ? As far as I know most wizarding positions seem to rely on use of wand magic. Also, I can't seem to find where they would learn the intricacies of the money business. Are these instructions just passed on word of mouth ?